# Automate function to not copy paste every single time

Tags: javascript

Im doing a calendar and i have 98 functions to automate.
Actually everything is working (for the 3 first test) but i dont want to copy paste 98 times the same function and switch everything everytime.

Here is my code so you can understand. (There is the 3 first functions and i want 98 like that) :

var heure8 = document.getElementById('h8').textContent;

var heure9 = document.getElementById('h9').textContent;

var heure10 = document.getElementById('h10').textContent;

var heure11 = document.getElementById('h11').textContent;

var heure12 = document.getElementById('h12').textContent;

var heure13 = document.getElementById('h13').textContent;

var heure14 = document.getElementById('h14').textContent;

var heure15 = document.getElementById('h15').textContent;

var heure16 = document.getElementById('h16').textContent;

var heure17 = document.getElementById('h17').textContent;

var heure18 = document.getElementById('h18').textContent;

var heure19 = document.getElementById('h19').textContent;

var heure20 = document.getElementById('h20').textContent;

var heure21 = document.getElementById('h21').textContent;

var heure22 = document.getElementById('h22').textContent;

```
document.getElementById('x1').addEventListener('click', creneau)
var ajout = 0;
function creneau(){
    var date1 = document.getElementById('w1').innerText;
    var date2 = document.getElementById('w2').innerText;
    var date3 = document.getElementById('w3').innerText;
    var date4 = document.getElementById('w4').innerText;
    var date5 = document.getElementById('w5').innerText;
    var date6 = document.getElementById('w6').innerText;
    var date7 = document.getElementById('w7').innerText;
    x1 = heure8+ ' à ' +heure9+ ' le ' +date1;
    
    
    if((ajout == 2)){
       ajout = 0; 
       }
    
        {     
    
    ajout += 1; 
     console.log(ajout)
    }   
if (ajout===1) {
   document.getElementById('r1').innerHTML = x1;
}
if(ajout===2) {
    document.getElementById('r1').innerHTML = '';
}
}
document.getElementById('x2').addEventListener('click', creneau2)
var ajout2 = 0;
function creneau2(){
    var date1 = document.getElementById('w1').innerText;
    var date2 = document.getElementById('w2').innerText;
    var date3 = document.getElementById('w3').innerText;
    var date4 = document.getElementById('w4').innerText;
    var date5 = document.getElementById('w5').innerText;
    var date6 = document.getElementById('w6').innerText;
    var date7 = document.getElementById('w7').innerText;
   var x2 = heure9+ ' à ' +heure10+ ' le ' +date1;
    
    
    if((ajout2 == 2)){
       ajout2 = 0; 
       }
    
        {     
    
    ajout2 += 1; 
     console.log(ajout2)
    }   
if (ajout2===1) {
   document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = x2;
}
if(ajout2===2) {
    document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = '';
}
}
document.getElementById('x3').addEventListener('click', creneau3)
var ajout3 = 0;
function creneau3(){
    var date1 = document.getElementById('w1').innerText;
    var date2 = document.getElementById('w2').innerText;
    var date3 = document.getElementById('w3').innerText;
    var date4 = document.getElementById('w4').innerText;
    var date5 = document.getElementById('w5').innerText;
    var date6 = document.getElementById('w6').innerText;
    var date7 = document.getElementById('w7').innerText;
   var x3 = heure10+ ' à ' +heure11+ ' le ' +date1;
    
    
    if((ajout3 == 2)){
       ajout3 = 0; 
       }
    
        {     
    
    ajout3 += 1; 
     console.log(ajout3)
    }   
if (ajout3===1) {
   document.getElementById('r3').innerHTML = x3;
}
if(ajout3===2) {
    document.getElementById('r3').innerHTML = '';
}
}
```

For this, everything is good, but i wanna do only one function that can do for my 98divs if you guys have ideas :p
Thanks a lot,
Zartex.

Comment: Does simple `for` loops from 1 to 98 work for you?

Comment: Maybe i dont know, i mean, in my head it's really clear but how can I proceed on my code to do a loop ? Thanks :)

Comment: In each loop iteration you handle one element. For instance `date = document.getElementById('w' + i)` (if `i` is your loop counter). And then work with `date`

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays for sequence of repeatable data data and loops like `for` to iterate over them.

```
let ajout_list = []
let x_list = []
for (let idx = 1; idx <= 98; idx++) {
   ajout_list[idx] = 0;
   document.getElementById('x' + idx).addEventListener('click', function() {
      // your repeated code
      // ugh... did you mean ajout there, because there's no way it will be 2 just a line below if you
      // never modified it since start of function?
      x_list[idx] = heure10+ ' à ' +heure11+ ' le ' +date1;

      if((ajout_list[idx] == 2)){
          ajout_list[idx] = 0;
      }
      // rest of your code modified along same lines
   })
}
```

Comment: I think this can work, but i dont understand few things, like the 'ajout_list'. It's always between 1 and 2 because it's only used to show the text when it's clicked once and hide it when it's clicked the second time etc etc

Comment: Imma try to be clear because i think this is not really. : I want that all 'x1' switch into x2 x3..x98. that's the only real important thing. The code is not repeated, it's changing a bit everytime so it's not working with your code ;(

Comment: `for` and `getElementById('x' + idx)` do just that. If you don't need to keep results for `ajout`, you can change it back. Your examples use different `x` every time - i.e. `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, but maybe you don't need to distinguish those too. Feel free to change those pieces back in that case.

Comment: Okey it worked at 80% ! Thank you, but i have a last problem, i wanna say to this line : if (ajout_list[idx]===1) {
    document.getElementById('r' + idx).innerHTML = x????;
 }
that the "x????" equals to the same x that we got first on the getelementbyid. document.getElementById('x' + idx).addEventListener('click', function() {

Because it's the name of my variable which says the day, hours etc. And i can not automate this one. So imma do 98 of them named x1 if its x1 (x2 if its x2 etc etc) on the first line. I hope you'll understand me :p

Comment: Replace it with `x_list[idx]` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you it's perfect, there is a last thing : How can I limit the number of click to 10 ?
Like i want that people can select Maximum of 10 slot/98div (which can be anywhere).
Thank you really really much man :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use loop for get elements from HTML like that:

```
creneau(elem) {
let id = elem.id;
for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    var date1 = document.getElementById(`w${i}`).innerText;
}
x1 = heure8 + ' à ' + heure9 + ' le ' + date1;}
```

Secondly, if you have three functions and all of them are doing the same thing just write only one time on js and call the function with the argument on the HTML side.
For example:

```
<input type="button" id="creneau" onclick="creneau(this)">
<input type="button" id="creneau1" onclick="creneau(this)">
<input type="button" id="creneau2" onclick="creneau(this)">
```

If you have any new questions don't hesitate to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your return, but no i have 98 functions to do which are doing same thing yeah but on different div (that's why it's x1-x2-x3..x98. It's switching hours and date so im lost ;/

Comment: Can you send the whole code with Code Snippet to help properly?

Comment: Okay i tried it on codepen can you see it here ? : https://codepen.io/Zartexx/pen/BawwaRL
Btw it is ugly because i didnot incorpore the whole css, but you can actually see when you click on the 3 first grey slot on top left (equals x1-x2-x3) so you can maybe understand

Comment: I changed your code and added new comment. Check it out

Comment: You can return your feedback if you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. I decided to change your too many codes to a little one. I deleted the big part of HTML and transfer it to JS. Just added 1 CSS and prepared everything to solve your problem. I used only 2 js functions to draw the table and onClick event. Now, u can use these functions to summarize and decrease your codes for working properly. Good luck.

```js
function drawTable() {
    const users = [];
    users.push('LUNDI');
    users.push('LUNDI');
    users.push('LUNDI');
    users.push('LUNDI');
    users.push('LUNDI');
    users.push('LUNDI');
    users.push('LUNDI');
    let text = "";
    let first = 1;
    let second = 14;
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        text += `<div class="gridtailledate try2 unselectable" id="w${i+1}" unselectable="on">${users[i]}</div>`
        for (let j = first; j <= second; j++) {
            text += `<div id="x${j}" onclick='clicked(x${j})' class="gridtaille bg"></div>`
        }
        first = second + 1;
        second += 14;
    }
    document.getElementById('contenugrid').innerHTML += text;
}

function clicked(param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

```css
.calendar {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 650px;
    width: 1450px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    border: solid black 2px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #5c0716;
}

.corps3 {
    width: 100%;
}

.bg {
    border-top: solid black 1px;
    border-left: solid black 1px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #707070;
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
    border-right: solid black 1px;
}

.contenugrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 8fr);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gridtailledate {
    width: 150px;
    height: calc(650px/8);
}

.gridtaille {
    width: calc(1300px/14);
    float: right;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 85px;
}

.center2 {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.center3 {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 75px;
}

.center4 {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 67px;
}

.couleurbackbody2 {
    background-color: #222222;
    z-index: 0;
}

.borderdown {
    border-top: white solid 2px;
}

.bordertop {
    border-bottom: white solid 2px;
}

.ontop {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.ondown {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.Coachname {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -10px;
    right: 87%;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

.fontstyle {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.fontstyleN {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
}

.aa {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 87.9%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.bb {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 83.4%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.cc {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 78.25%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.dd {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 73.1%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.ee {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 68.2%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.ff {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 63.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.gg {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 58.4%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.hh {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 53.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.ii {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 48.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.jj {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 43.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.kk {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 38.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.ll {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 33.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.mm {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 28.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.nn {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 23.3%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.oo {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 27px;
    right: 19.7%;
    padding-top: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    color: white;
}

.policedate {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

.weeks {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 4;
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.arrowleft {
    color: #5c0716;
    right: 61%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 74%;
}

.arrowright {
    color: #5c0716;
    left: 61%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 74%;
}

.try {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.try2 {
    color: white;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.coachtopleft {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC';
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    color: black;
}

.recap {
    width: 280px;
    height: 550px;
    border: black solid 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    margin-top: 3%;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #5c0716;
    text-align: center;
}

.buttonpay {
    width: 280px;
    height: 90.4px;
    border: black solid 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    margin-top: 33%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #5c0716;
}

.textrecap {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 35px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

.borderrecap {
    width: 276px;
    height: 81.25px;
    border-bottom: solid black 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 84.8%;
    position: absolute;
}

.textpay {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 26px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

.indexz {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: fit-content;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.Resatxt {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.creneautxt {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 35px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

.margintop {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body onload="drawTable()">

    <div id="recap" class="recap">
        <p unselectable="on" class="textrecap unselectable">RECAPITULATIF DE LA COMMANDE</p>
        <div class="margintop">
            <div class="creneautxt" id="r1"></div>
            <div class="creneautxt" id="r2"></div>
            <div class="creneautxt" id="r3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="borderrecap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonpay ">
        <p class="textpay unselectable" unselectable="on">RÉSERVER</p>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class="contenugrid" id="contenugrid">
            <div class="gridtailledate coachtopleft unselectable" unselectable="on">ZARTEX</div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h8" class="aa unselectable" unselectable="on">8:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h9" class="bb unselectable" unselectable="on">9:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h10" class="cc unselectable" unselectable="on">10:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h11" class="dd unselectable" unselectable="on">11:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h12" class="ee unselectable" unselectable="on">12:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h13" class="ff unselectable" unselectable="on">13:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h14" class="gg unselectable" unselectable="on">14:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h15" class="hh unselectable" unselectable="on">15:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h16" class="ii unselectable" unselectable="on">16:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h17" class="jj unselectable" unselectable="on">17:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h18" class="kk unselectable" unselectable="on">18:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h19" class="ll unselectable" unselectable="on">19:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h20" class="mm unselectable" unselectable="on">20:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="gridtaille">
                <div id="h21" class="nn unselectable" unselectable="on">21:00</div>
                <div id="h22" class="oo unselectable" unselectable="on">22:00</div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</body>

</html>
```